# OpenXml How To Replace FieldCode Value

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have a word document with a mail merge field.
I am trying to replace the mail merge field with a value using OpenXml.

I can select the field using:

```
FieldCode field = document.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<FieldCode>().where(x => x.Text == "MERGEFIELD  Field_B  \* MERGEFORMAT")
```

But then have no way to change the value once I find the right field?
Changing the text property only changes the field code and not the value.

Here is the xml from the word document showing this field.

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00BE3C49">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00BE3C49">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  Field_B  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00BE3C49">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00BE3C49">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>«Field_B»</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00BE3C49">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
</w:r>
```

Comment: hey, do you have the solution for this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to doing it yourself, you could try http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1